# Align Different Elements Horizontally

Tags: css

What's the best way to align these elements? I want to avoid using margin-top on the check mark icons to align them to the centerline of the buttons.

**I Want To Avoid This**

```
 <div class="icon check" style="margin-top:11px;"></div>
```

Live example here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/castonzo/WJk9b/7/)

[image]

```
<div id="statusbar">
 <div class="icon check"></div> <a class="btn inactive" href="">Button 1</a>
 <div class="icon check"></div> <a class="btn inactive" href="">Button 2</a>
 <div class="icon check"></div> <a class="btn inactive" href="">Button 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your CSS as well?

Comment: How do you want them aligned? Can you set up a jsfiddle? The `vertical-align` property may help you here.

Comment: I want the checkbox icons to line up with the buttons on the horizontal plane. So imagine adding padding-top:20px; to the checkbox icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way is to set `vertical-align:middle` to the wrapper and using `display:inline-block` for the child like this:

```
<div id="statusbar">
 <div class="icon check"></div> <a class="btn inactive" href="">Button 1</a>
 <div class="icon check"></div> <a class="btn inactive" href="">Button 2</a>
 <div class="icon check"></div> <a class="btn inactive" href="">Button 3</a>
</div>

.icon{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
}

.inactive{
     display: inline-block;
}

#statusbar{
    height:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Xhu/)

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the height of the checkbox icons to be equal to the button height, then centering the checkbox background image vertically. Depending on how the button height is set, this could be by font-size and line-height, or just a height. Then I'd use:

```
.icon {
  background-position: 0 center;
}
```

Please share some of your CSS or a JSFiddle if that doesn't help.

Comment: The button css specifies height:auto